# Source / Medium stripped off in GA4 event. Can # delimiter be the reason?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Been tracking UA and GA4 in parallel. Running some campaigns  with `utm_source=google` and `utm_medium=metasearch`.

For the same given period, UA reports the source/medium values correctly.
[image]

Whilst GA4 is completely missing it:
[image]

Upon further investigation, I've realised that those *google / metasearch* is the only one value that comes from UTMs (all others are referrals).

So I check the collected events in developer console and in the GA4 event all UTMs are being stripped off:

[image]

Whilst in UA they are there:
[image]

Probably I've found what the issue is and it's related to the utl structure.

Take this: `https://example.com/#/availability?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test`

Can the `#` delimiter cause the issue?

And if so, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I too facing the same issue, any workaround for this please let me know

Comment: I would absolutely say the fragment identifier (#) is to blame here. UTM params are taken from *URL query parameters*; here you have NO query parameters (everything after # is a fragment identifier).

Comment: e.g. try https://example.com/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test2#/availability